# Scoping f.collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models, named-scopes

I've got a model that I'm using a collection_select on and I'd like to scope it to show only accounts that are open.  To accomplish this, I've added a boolean field to my `account` model, defaulting to `false`.

Here's my attempt at that in my account model:

```
def open_accounts
    self.where(account_closed: false)
end
```

And where I'm attempting to use that method in another model's view:

```
<%= f.collection_select :account_id, current_user.accounts.open_accounts, :id, :registration %>
```

I'm running into a no method error, despite trying to add the method to both my `user` and my `account` models.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this boolean field exist in your database schema? Have you also migrated your database?

Comment: It does exist and it has been migrated

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears I may have asked too soon.  Feel free to comment on the appropriateness of this solution:

Added `scope :open_accounts, -> {where(account_closed: [nil, false])}` to my `account` model.  The rest is the same as above.